# how to highlight sentences based on sentence index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text editor where the user enters some texts/paragraph and calls the API when I click submit. The back-end splits the whole paragraph into sentences and sends them in an array in the response. Now I store the sentences array into a state and then display it using map() function, I also store the 'hard' object into a hardIndex state. I have to highlight the sentences whose indexes are in the hardIndex state, here in my example response '0' and '2nd' sentences need to be highlighted which I'm unable to do. Can someone show me how to highlight those sentences whose indexes are there in the 'hardIndex' state?

The api sends a response like:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    "The computer runs on a three-step cycle namely input, process, and output.",
    "Also, the computer follows this cycle in every process it was asked to do. ",
    "In simple words, the process can be explained in this way. ",
  ],
  "hard": [
    0,
    2
  ] //index of sentences which needs to be highlighted
```

I have written his so far

```
states={
hard:[],
sentencesHard: []
}


  performSentenceAnalysis = async () => {
    const { enteredText } = this.state;

    const body = { snippetdesc: enteredText };
    const stringifiedBody = JSON.stringify(body);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: stringifiedBody
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/readability";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);  
      const result = await response.json();

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sentencesHard: result.sentences,
        hardIndex: result.hard,
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


//the sentences array is displayed here and I need to highlight those sentences whose indexes are in the hard array

<div className="lastBox">
          { this.state.sentencesHard.map(sentence =>{
            return(
               <div>
                 {sentence}
               </div>
               )
           }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator and see if the index of the string you're iterating over is contained in the `hard` array:

```
<div className="lastBox"> {
  this.state.sentencesHard.map((sentence, i) => (
   <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.hardIndex.includes(i) ? 'yellow' : 'initial' }}>
     {sentence}
   </div>
  ))
} </div>
```

(if you had a whole lot of sentences, you might transform the array into a Set beforehand to reduce computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`)

Your state property names are a bit confusing. Your current `hardIndex` is actually an array, not an index, and only *some* of your `sentencesHard` are actually hard (an index of `hardIndex`). Maybe consider changing the state properties to what the API returns:

```
this.setState(() => result);
```

and then refer to the `sentences` and `hard` properties. (Or maybe rename the `hard` property to `hardIndicies`, to make it clearer what it actually is)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. Also I will keep in mind about setting the state part. However, I was wondering if I can join all the sentences from the `sentences` array and kinda make it look like a paragraph as right now, it shows each sentence separately and the background color is all over the place and kinda looks ugly. I was hoping if the sentences array could actually be displayed like a paragraph as it was originally typed  by the user or even close to that instead of showing each line separately

Comment: You're currently mapping to an array of `<div>`s, which have line breaks between them. If you don't want linebreaks, you can use `span`s instead

Comment: okay, got it. but there's no way of knowing paragraph breaks? or can I ask the machine learning guys to do something so that there are the paragraph breaks as well like the original text as typed by the user

Comment: Given that *The api sends a response like:...*, it doesn't look like the API currently differentiates between paragraphs. I'm sure there's a way to do it, but you would have to alter the back-end logic